# SQL add constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an table employees , and I want to add an constraint which makes me able to have **ONLY** one employee with id_manager **null**.. 
I have a sample from my code , but I think it's wrong..

```
ALTER TABLE employees ADD CONSTRAINT u_t UNIQUE (id_manager);
```

And this is the error I get.

```
SQL Error: ORA-02299: (OPREAC_IDD.U_T)
02299. 00000 - "cannot validate (%s.%s) - duplicate keys found"
*Cause:    an alter table validating constraint failed because the table has
       duplicate key values.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say:

> I want to add a constraint which makes me able to have **ONLY** one employee with `id_manager` **null**.

So if I understand this correctly, you're ok with having duplicates in the `id_manager` column.  The only thing you're trying to restrict is making sure that no more than one row can have `null` as the value for `id_manager`.

If that's the case, you'll want to create a unique index with an expression so that only null values are considered and validated:

```
create unique index emp_idx
on employees (case when id_manager is null then 1 end)
```